# Why the json.decoder.JSONDecodeError?

Tags: python, json, logging

I'm trying to configure my Python logging module using [logging.config.dictConfig()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig)

However, my JSON file appears to be corrupt even though it works as a Python dict with `false` changed to `False`, so I don't think it's a syntax error.

My code says:

```
import json

with open('logging_config.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

My `logging_config.json` file is:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "disable_existing_loggers": false,
  "formatters": {
    "standard": {
      "format": "[%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"
    },
  },
  "handlers": {
    "default": {
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "formatter": "standard",
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
    },
  },
  "loggers": {
    "": {
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "level": "INFO",
      "propagate": true
    },
    "myfunc": {
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "propagate": false
    },
  }
}
```

When I run that simple program, I get an error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 8 column 3 (char 156)`

What could be causing the JSON decoder to fail?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The JSON parser is expecting a certain type of value for each key. A string is one accepted value, an integer another. You're trying to insert a boolean, but there is a difference between upper and lowercase for booleans. Only one is a valid boolean. Here's some [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)

Comment: @ajoseps that isn't the issue. The issue is you have an extraneous comma, so JSON expects a key. How was this JSON generated? It certainly wasn't by the python `json` module

Comment: It used to be a Python dict which I converted manually. Python forgives the extra commas but json doesn't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have multiple extraneous commas which will break the JSON deserialization.

Here's your original JSON with every extraneous comma pointed out:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "disable_existing_loggers": false,
  "formatters": {
    "standard": {
      "format": "[%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"
    }, # <--- extraneous comma
  },
  "handlers": {
    "default": {
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "formatter": "standard",
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler", # <--- extraneous comma
    }, # <--- extraneous comma
  },
  "loggers": {
    "": {
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "level": "INFO",
      "propagate": true
    },
    "myfunc": {
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "propagate": false
    }, # <--- extraneous comma
  }
}
```

Removing those, this is now a valid JSON document:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "standard": {
            "format": "[%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "default": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "standard",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "handlers": ["default"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": true
        },
        "myfunc": {
            "handlers": ["default"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, Python forgives these extra commas. I missed them when converting the Python to json. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As others already answered, there are some excess commas in your JSON.

You could feed your JSON to https://jsonlint.com/ ; it tends to give more useful help messages.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your JSON is invalid. this one JSON is valid.
I removed extra commas from your JSON.
You can use any JSON validator to fix it.

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "disable_existing_loggers": false,
  "formatters": 
  {
    "standard": 
    {
      "format": "[%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"
    }
  },
  "handlers": 
  {
    "default": 
    {
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "formatter": "standard",
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler"
    }
  },
  "loggers": 
  {
    "": 
    {
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "level": "INFO",
      "propagate": true
    },
    "myfunc": 
    {
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "propagate": false
    }
  }
}
```